# Laravel Controller not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-controller

I'm learning laravel and I've tried to create a Controller.
I'm really new, so, please, elaborate.

I've used the following command to create the Controller

```
php artisan make:controller Api/EstadoController
```

So, EstadoController is under Controllers/Api

I also created a route at api.php

```
Route::namespace('API')->name('api.')->group(function() {
  Route::get('/estados', 'EstadoController@index')->name('estados');
});
```

EstadoController has index function and correct namespace:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class EstadoController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
      return Estado::all();
    }
}
```

Here is the error page:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing

> API

to

> Api

in my route resolved, like route creation.

Route:

```
Route::namespace('Api')->name('api.')->group(function() {
  Route::get('/estados', 'EstadoController@index')->name('estados');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to make route like this:

Route::get('/estados', 'Api\EstadoController@index');